# Haskell List of lists operations

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to traverse through a list of lists and perform an operation on each list.

If I have a list like

```
[[("vT",T),("vF",T)],[("vT",T),("vF",F)],[("vT",F),("vF",T)],[("vT",T),("vF",M)],[("vT",M),("vF",T)],[("vT",M),("vF",M)],[("vT",F),("vF",F)],[("vT",F),("vF",M)],[("vT",M),("vF",F)]]
```

How can I create a function that sets an `x = [("vT",T),("vF",T)]`, so that I can use this x to perform an operation, and then set `x = [("vT",T),("vF",F)]` and so on and then have the answer of each returned in a list?

Comment: Are you looking for `map`?

Comment: Can you elaborate? For example show some sample input, and what you'd expect the output to be.

Comment: I added more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) to apply a function to each element of a list - here's a complete example:

```
data Tribool = T | F | M deriving Show

my_data = [
    [("vT",T),("vF",T)],
    [("vT",T),("vF",F)],
    [("vT",F),("vF",T)],
    [("vT",T),("vF",M)],
    [("vT",M),("vF",T)],
    [("vT",M),("vF",M)],
    [("vT",F),("vF",F)],
    [("vT",F),("vF",M)],
    [("vT",M),("vF",F)]
  ]

f x = reverse x -- example function

processed_data = map f my_data
```